# How to save java serialized objects into database?

Tags: java, database, serialization

Now, I have 200k objects in java, each of which have an unique ID. I will access them randomly later. So I want to save these objects into a database. Which kind of database should be a good choice? The relational database(MySQL) or some NoSQL database?

Comment: Do you need to store relations between the objects or just reference the objects by id?

Comment: If you only want to access by id any NoSQL-DB can do this.

Comment: This depends a lot on your other requirements. If retrieval by a unique ID is all you need is a commonly overlooked "database" type called "plain files" :-)

Comment: What's about performance requirements? What's about data growing? What the others persistence requirement might you have?

Comment: My need is simple, just access the objects by id. The number of objects is at most 200k. BTW, I want to store these objects on disk, not only in RAM, so maybe Berkeley DB would not help. (Am I right?)

Answer (score 1):

I remember once working on a project where someone suggested that the ORM layer was unnecessary and over complicated the whole design.
He proposed that binary serializations should be written to a database table using the Object Id/Hash code, and a blob for the serialized object.

The problem that was pointed out with that approach occurs when the structure of a serialized Class changes, then all of the previously serialized object instancess need to be migrated/evolved.

So beware of storing a binary/serialized representation of an object for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I use the Berkeley DB, which is an embedded database which could access only through programming language.